# Why "uniq/uniq!" method is not working on following array

Tags: ruby

The `var_arry` contains the all *instance variables* of the class. But I want the array without duplicates. How can I get please help me.

```
file = open("sample.txt")    
var_arr = []

file.each do |line|
 var = line.match /@(\w+_\w+|\w+)/
  if var != nil
   var_arr << var
  end
end
puts var_arr.uniq!
```

I get following output. But I want to eliminate the duplicate values for this I use `.uniq!` method but it cant work

```
@event
@event
@event
@event
@event_participants
@event_participants
@event_participants
@event_participants
@event_participants
@event_participants
@event_participants
@event_participants
@project
@event
@project
@events
@projects
@events
@subscription
@admin
@subscription
@owners
@projects
@projects
@projects
@project_files
@project_file
@project_file
@project_file
@project_file
@sort_option
@sort_direction
@sort_filter
@sort_filter
@sort_filter
@sort_filter
@sort_filter
@sort_filter
@sort_filter
@sort_option
@sort_option
@sort_option
@sort_option
@sort_option
@sort_direction
@sort_direction
@sort_direction
@sort_direction
@sort_direction
@sort_filter
@projects
@projects
@sort_direction
@projects
@projects
@sort_option
@sort_filter
@projects
@projects
@message_template
@message_template
@message_template
@message_template
@message_template
@message_template
@message_template
@drag_evnt
@drag_evnt
```

Comment: The var_arry contains the all instance variables of the sample.txt file  not a class.

Comment: Write in your question what it actually has and what do you want it has

Comment: post what you get as `var_arr` object

Comment: The var_arr has duplicate values I want unique values in var_arr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put instances of [`MatchData`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/MatchData.html) in your array, produced by this line:

```
var = line.match /@(\w+_\w+|\w+)/
```

Don’t be confused by `puts` output, it calls `to_s` internally on printed entities, so you get stringified representation of your actual `MatchData` instances.

[`Array#uniq!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq-21) compares values by it’s `hash` and `eql?` for efficiency. To put strings, use:

```
var[1] if var[1]
```

Or, even better:

```
lines = file.map do |line|
  $1 if line =~ /@(\w+_\w+|\w+)/
end.compact.uniq
```

The latter will map lines to either matched value or nil. `compact` will get rid of nils and `uniq` will do what you expected.